# How to scrape a page generated using flutter javascript code dynamically

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape page to download a file by clicking on download button image in website below. I couldn't inspect that element to find its id for click using selenium . After looking at source code found that its a javascript flutter code and it can't be inspected. Sharing the screenshot of page and page source code below.

```
<html><head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="sms">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

  <title>SMS</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.37.1/bin/canvaskit.js"></script><style></style><meta flt-viewport="" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"><meta id="flutterweb-theme" name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"></head>
<body flt-renderer="canvaskit (auto-selected)" flt-build-mode="release" spellcheck="false" style="position: fixed; inset: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; user-select: none; touch-action: none; font: 14px sans-serif; color: red;">
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = '3887127261';
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plain <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>


<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script><flt-file-picker-inputs id="__file_picker_web-file-input"></flt-file-picker-inputs><script src="assets/packages/flutter_dropzone_web/assets/flutter_dropzone.js" type="application/javascript" defer=""></script><flt-glass-pane style="position: absolute; inset: 0px;"></flt-glass-pane></body></html>
```

Download button form page:
[image]

I tried following code to find the html generated using above flutter javascript code with no luck.  Here is the code I have tried so far.

`driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML")`

and
`driver.page_source`

both gives same page actual source code above. I need actually html generated with download image button.

How can I find some id/class/img tag of the Download button to click using selenium for file download? Any help highly appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium's WebDriverWait to wait for the element to become clickable or visible on the page. Even though you can't directly inspect the element, you can still use its XPath or CSS selector if you know how to locate it.

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75368537/19949392

Comment: first we need to locate by either inspecting or by loading flutter javascript the element to click. thats where I am stuck.